# Resharper says I shouldn't use List<T>

Tags: c#, list, resharper, ienumerable

I have a method:

```
static void FileChangesDetected(List<ChangedFiles> files)
```

I used Visual Studio 2010 and Resharper. Resharper always recommends that I change the `List<T>` to `IEnumerable<T>`, and I'm wondering why this is.

In the method, I simply do this:

```
 foreach (var file in files)
 { ... }
```

Is there a benefit of using `IEnumerable<T>` rather than `List<T>`?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It all has to do with [LSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) (Liskov substitution principle).

Basically, instead of using implementations, it is better to code to abstractions.

In this specific case, if all you do is loop over the list, you can use `IEnumerable<T>` as the simplest abstraction - this way you don't *have* to use a `List<T>`, but *any* collection type in your function.

This allows your functions to be more reusable and reduces [coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29).

Comment: IEnumerable is simpler than ICollection

Comment: IEnumerable, not ICollection.

Comment: Thanks. Is it because using IEnumerable/ICollection uses less system resource, or is more efficient than using List<>, because List<> provides more methods, which I am not using?

Comment: @cdotlister - It has nothing to do with resources, but with software design. It is better _design_.

Comment: @cdolister - For instance, say I already have have a (old school, or just not-so-well-designed) library method which returns an array... which IS IEnumerable, but IS NOT a List... so I could pass it your useful `FastForward(IEnumerable<Time>)` method, without having to first convert it to a List.

Comment: Sorry to be picky, but Liskov does not stipulate that you should or must substituate the supertype wherever possible, it just says that it should *always* be possible. There is no notion of such an advice as "it's better to use abstraction" in Liskov. What is true, though, is, if your code follows Liskov principle, then you can apply this R# recommendation safely.

Answer (score 3):

Resharper suggests that your method doesn't need really require `List<T>` as a parameter and can easily work with `IEnumerable<T>`. Which means that you can make you method more generic.

Answer (score 3):

If you are just iterating of your `files`, then it does not have to be a List<>. Your code would also work with an array. Or more general: It will work with anything you can iterate over. That's expressed by IEnumerable<>. So the usage of List<> restricts the usage of you message without any need. The ReSharper method is just a hint for that.

Answer (score 2):

Because in your code, you only use the fact that `files` is an `IEnumerable<ChangedFiles>`, you don't use for example Count, nor Add.

Even if later on, you want to use List specific methods (with Add or Count methods), it's always better to use an interface: `IList<ChangedFiles>` instead of a concrete implementation.

Answer (score 1):

You will still be able to the foreach even if you change it to

```
IEnumerable<ChangedFiles>
```

or

```
ICollection<ChangedFiles>
```